# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+

Tags: flutter, google-play-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CONgb.png)FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :location
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s

Answer (score 3):

Main problem that location:3.2.4 has no strict Android dependency version play-services-location:16.+ and Gradle can't list version because google.bintray.com is down

Straight way to workaround this problem is to add Gradle Constraints on transitive dependency and specify concrete version

You have to edit your project file ***app/build.gradle***

```
dependencies {
...
  constraints {
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location') {
        version {
            strictly "16.0.0"
        }
        because 'location: 3.2.4 does not specify version & google.bintray.com answers 502 Bad Gateway'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The repository URL is wrong; you might have to add `google()`:

https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=loca#com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.0

Comment: Thank you for responding. Actually, I'm working with Flutter so I don't have any idea about Android. Can you tell me in which file I need to fix it?

Comment: @GulAhmed How shall I know? The above is an error message, without the code.