# Flutter Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6).

Required by:
project :app
> Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

**app-level/buildgradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the 
local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
  (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.deligence.hookup4u2"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    // Use code below for production build
    // For debug mode you need to comment above lines of code
    // Issue with 'libflutter.so'
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

 dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
}
```

**projectlevel/buildGradle**

```
  buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
   repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }

dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

 rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
 subprojects {
 project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
 }
 subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem that google.bintray.com is down but version of com.facebook.android:facebook-login is not specified strictly.

This **[5,6)** mean it has versions range [Gradle Declaring Versions and Ranges](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html)

1. Search for versions of *com.facebook.android:facebook-login* [Maven search](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-login). We have 5.15.x
2. Constrain your transitive dependency with maximum possible version 5.15.3

Edit your project **app/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  constraints {
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login') {
        version {
            strictly '5.15.3'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After editing the above changes
i Got another error

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :location
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.

Comment: it has same reason add constraints as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327441/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata-could-not-resolve-com-go/70363920#70363920

Comment: @Sergey Salnikov, thanks - works as described